# Why is it important to use Discriminator when implementing Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I've read mongoose documentation but still didn't get it, when i create a mongoose schema I can create fields that I might not use like

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fruit: [{
       color: String,
       season: String
   }],
   book: [{
       pages:String,
       author: String
  }]
]);
```

Then if i miss book object, it won't be written on product model so why should I use discriminators IF I'm going to get same result can some1 explains please.

Comment: It's a really broad topic. https://www.google.com/search?q=polymorphism You would probably be better off presenting a question in the form of something you actually need to achieve. General "I want to learn about a topic" questions are really not in the scope of answers for this site. Still you can always research from that link.

Comment: thanks for the advice.